# Connotes vs Connotates

Tags: word-choice, word-usage

Can someone recommend proper usage of the word "connotate", for example, in a sentence? I am having difficulty distinguishing when to use *connote* over *connotates*.

> The word 'remaining' *connotes* (or *connotates*?) continuing action as before...

Comment: [Collins](https://www.collinsdictionary.com/us/dictionary/english/connotate): << _connotate_ [in British English] verb (transitive)
**obsolete**: 
to connote  >>

Comment: From connotation, you could produce connotate. But then, I have heard orientation produce *orientate*, and conversation *conversate*, and not just once.

Comment: Also, 'remaining' **denotes** continuing, as opposed to 'connotes' it. While a denotation is the dictionary definition, a connotation is the more subtle hint a word gives. "I've been waiting for you" does denote the wait, neutrally, but may connote impatience.

Comment: Some similar forms like *orientate* are [controversial](https://www.merriam-webster.com/grammar/orient-or-orientate-is-it-a-real-word) and inspire a lot of anger; fortunately connotate has a more civil debate. Anyway [this question](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/582696/why-do-the-british-navigate-and-orientate-but-not-conversate-or-confrontate) covers a few similar words.

Comment: @StuartF: Yes - of course, everyone knows the only correct word is "orientationalise" ;-)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

According to the [Online Etymology Dictionary](https://www.etymonline.com/word/connotate#etymonline_v_28660):

> **connotate (v.)**
> "to signify secondarily," 1590s, from Medieval Latin connotatus, past participle of connotare "signify in addition to the main meaning," a term in logic (see connotation). **It is now obsolete, replaced by connote**.

Emphasis mine. A [Google Ngram](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=connote%2Cconnotate&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=26&smoothing=0#) backs it up:

[image]

So, to answer your question, **there is no proper usage of the word *connotate* in modern English.**

Just use *connote*.

Answer (score 0):

"Connote" is by far the most common version. "Connotate", in addition to being rare itself, interferes with the noun form of "connote", "connotation".

Answer (score -2):

As someone who studied Latin at school, connotate is by far the prettier version, and connote is an ugly neologism. However, they do mean slightly different things. In general, the extra -at signifies repetivity or a continuing state, whereas without suggests an individual occurrence. One could say "in general, this symbol connotates one thing, but in this context it connotes something else". I don't give two figs though whether I am considered archaic for using language thus.

Comment: English is not Latin. To judge an English word by your knowledge of Latin could be seen as a form of [etymological fallacy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Etymological_fallacy).