# Why do the British navigate, and orientate, but not conversate or confrontate?

Tags: american-english, british-english

Americans orient, Britons orientate. Both amputate when performing an amputation. In a conversation, one converses but doesn't conversate. But both Americans and Brits merely compute, rather than computate. And in a confrontation, both confront, rather than confrontate.

What are these rules determined by?

Comment: "Britons conversate"...do we? I can't say I've ever heard anyone use that word.

Comment: Well, Jamaicans at least do. Or certainly various ones that I've met before.

Comment: I never heard or saw the word *conversate* in Britain. Not in England, Scotland, Wales or Ireland. We converse. Your question needs editing to remove this fallacy.

Comment: @Anton Most likely in Scunthorpe.

Comment: There are no rules. They are preferences and the usage through history determines them. They are not always stable and sometimes both versions can be used in AmE or BrE, but one version might be more common in one of them. These are often created through back-formation. For example, _orient_ is earlier than _orientate_, and it is from French _orienter_. _Orientate_ is created through back-formation from _orientation_ or _orientator_ and the earliest usages appear in ecclesiological (church architecture and adornment) texts in BrE, and early works in this area could be a big influence.

Comment: 'AmE' and 'BrE' can be extremely unhelpful terms, as they are obviously ill-defined yet seem to imply that they are fixed canons. '... sometimes both versions can be found in the US and the UK, but one version might be more common in one of the regions.'

Comment: Does this answer your main question? ["Object oriented" vs. "object orientated"](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/516439/object-oriented-vs-object-orientated) The broader issues can be researched at say Etymon.

Comment: 'AmE' and 'BrE' are helpful terms and they are used in linguistics. We are talking about languages here. It is obvious that they represent a region or regions, people who speak them and the corpus (collection of written and spoken language).